# Accessing the bitly OAuth2 API from R

Tags: r, api, bit.ly

I'd like to be able to access the [bitly OAuth2 api](http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html) from R and was wondering whether there were any example implementations, or better still, R libraries/wrappers for the bitly API around?

The twitteR library span off an [R OAuth library, ROAuth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROAuth/index.html), but this presumably doesn't support OAuth2? Or will OAuth2 accept the OAuth1 overtures?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `httr` - it's in the veins of the [packages' examples on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/httr/tree/master/demo):

```
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)

# 1. Find OAuth settings for bit.ly:
# http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html
bitly <- oauth_endpoint(
  authorize = "https://bitly.com/oauth/authorize",
  access = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token")

# 2. Register an application at http://dev.bitly.com/my_apps.html
# Insert your values below - if secret is omitted, it will look it up in
# the BITLY_CONSUMER_SECRET environmental variable.
myapp <- oauth_app("bitly", 
                   key = ".............................", # Client ID
                   secret = "............................") # Client Secret

bitly_token <- oauth2.0_token(bitly, myapp, cache = FALSE) 

# 4. Use API
req <- GET("https://api-ssl.bit.ly/v3/user/info", query = list(access_token = bitly_token$credentials$access_token))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)$data$profile_url
# [1] "http://bitly.com/u/lukeanker"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written three fxns so far within a package that hits other APIs here: https://github.com/ropensci/raltmet/tree/master/R

The three fxns gets clickc based on users, expand URLs and shorten URLs

Install via:

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("raltmet", "ropensci")
require(raltmet)
```

Comment: If you think it's worth writing a whole R package for bitly, that could be done too. I guess you are asking about OAuth, and my functions just use API keys instead

Comment: Thanks Scott - the plan is actually a suite of libraries/tools for doing general tracking/stats of resources across various online apps, eg tracking mentions of academic papers and educational resources in local repositories. I need to sketch an indicative meta-package/package bundle framework out really... Re OAuth2, it seemed like a useful general package. As to a bespoke bitly library, maybe it would be useful?

Comment: I started a repo https://github.com/ropensci/rbitly. Let us know if you'd like to contribute to it and we can add you in. If this isn't worth having as a separate repo, we can fold it into raltmet at some future time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with the yet to be updated on CRAN version of ROAUth ( `ROAuth 0.92`). I have a working copy available [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2223411/ROAuth_0.92.0.tar.gz). Once you install `ROAuth` from this source, download a copy of `RMendeley` to test out how R works with oauth.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("rmendeley", "ropensci")
```